# Change the message Upload primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I change the message that primefaces show when the file is not correct. 
I need to change this to spanish.

```
<p:fileUpload fileLimitMessage="hola2" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.CargaArchivoForzada}" id="fileArchivoForzada" label="Buscar" cancelLabel="Borrar"
    class="ui-g-12" update="msjeForzada pnlResumenForzada btnCargarCasos" advanced="true"   dragDropSupport="false" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls)$/"/>
    <p:growl id="msjeForzada" showDetail="true" />
```

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAt46.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this

> invalidFileMessage="Error formato de archivo"